# Do certain string patterns affect query performance on a VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, varchar

I am a beginner on MySQL Administration and performance problems. Now this is confusing me.

I have a `VARCHAR` column `identity`, the string in it is consisted of a Class type and an id, like `note:123`, `user:4` to identify a row in one type of entity.

There are 5 class names for now.

Since the string could be constructed as `note:123` or `123:note`, either holds the meaning of it, I am wondering does `123:note` will have better query performance if I do `select * from table where identity='123:note'` than the other? I am thinking that `123:note` will have more variety from the beginning of string, because the id is at the front.

Or it just doesn't matter?

UPDATE:
the `identity` field is just a redundant field for query, the `type` and `id` are actually stored in other two fields in the same table.

So:

1st, `where type='note' and id=123'` is definitely faster than `where identity in ('note:123', 'user:456')`. I think it's definitely faster, right?

2nd, if I have to have this redundant column, `note:123` or `123:note` which pattern is faster when I do `where identity in ('note:123', 'user:456')`, and the length of identity is 20.

And here is create info: `likeable_identity` is the `identity` field I am talking about.

```
CREATE TABLE `likes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `likeable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `likeable_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `likeable_identity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_likes_on_user_id_and_likeable_id_and_likeable_type` (`user_id`,`likeable_id`,`likeable_type`),
  KEY `index_likes_on_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8814 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G` on the table where identity is located. If for security purposes you can't do that, then at least tell me what the length of the VARCHAR field is. You can also run this and post the output in the question body : SELECT identity FROM tblname `PROCEDURE ANALYSE();`

Comment: Why wouldn't you store these two separate pieces of data in two separate columns? Then you can worry about optimizing searches for one or the other without worrying about how you decided to munge them together for some reason.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, they are also stored in other two fields, `type` and `id`, this `identity` field is a redundant field for easier searching, only need one `where` clause.

Comment: Why are you storing them twice? Why doesn't your query go after the columns where they're stored on their own?

Comment: @AaronBertrand easier to do on the application side, proposed by the application guys, and there's mechanism from the application side to ensure that they are consistent. It's like the `type` and `id` fields are actually used as foreign key and the `identity` field consisted by `type` and `id` are used for some certain query.

Comment: Then you need to decide whether you want ease of programming or performance. In this case, you can't have both very easily. Do you want it to be a little harder for a query you're going to write once, or do you want to pay a performance penalty every single time it's executed? I'd suggest that changing the query to look at the right column (and getting rid of the absolutely needless redundant storage of the same data) will be worth it. If you don't, *shrug*...

Comment: @AaronBertrand So, I am thinking of two questions now. 1st, `where type='note' and id='123'` is definitely faster than `where identity='note:123'` right? 2nd, if we have to have this `identity` field, which pattern is faster in your opinion? or how could I test it?

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

1) Store the data in two columns.

2) Normalize 'type' to a separate table, so you'll only put an INT into your index rather than a varchar(255).

3) Switch to UNSIGNED INT for the ids, and maybe TINYINT for the types.

4) Tell the app people to learn about multiple WHERE clauses for their SQL and give them a good index.

3) Once you do those, your question might become, "should my composite index be (id,type) or (type,id)?"

Comment: For step 2, you can also use an [`enum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) data type in MySQL to get the benefits of an integer for indexing, potentially without needing any changes to your application. Using a separate table is a more robust, database-portable solution though.

Comment: There are scary warnings about ALTERing existing enum columns.  I use them for sets that never change (yes/no), but not for things that might change (types).